# Double rule in .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is the 1st time I am using stackoverflow, I usually find answers to my questions about development thanks to Google, or with the help of some friends. Not this time !

I am in trouble with a .htaccess file where I want to define a double rule.
Initally I had this code for URL rewriting :

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?query=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

It is working like a charm, but I saw that many of the pages of the website indexed by Google where duplicated on a subdomain of my website, so I decided to add this code in the .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mydomain.com/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please notice that I have added this code, just after the RewriteEngine on.
The result is almost what I expect, the 301 redirection from subdomain such as mail.domain.com/mypage.html is working and leads to www.domain.com/mypage.html but the second rule for URL rewriting pages is like cancelled ! So all pages which use the second rule have a 404 error.

I have tested many different things but couldn't figure out how to fix that ?
Anyone has a tip to help me success ?

Thanks in advance guys !

Comment: Try clearing the browser cache and test again (always do that every now and then since 301 responses are cached by the browser). There should be an infinite loop as suggested by lanzz.

Comment: Better add [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) flag to rewrite rule rather than adding `&%{QUERY_STRING}` to the final url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mydomain.com/$
```

This condition *always* matches, since you are asking for a hostname that does not end in `mydomain.com/`; `%{HTTP_HOST}` will *never* end in a slash, since it only contains the hostname with no path. Since the condition always matches, its `RewriteRule` is always in effect, and it is marked as `[L]` (last rule). I have no idea why it does not result in an redirection loop, probably some short-circuit logic in `mod_rewrite` that stops the rewriting when the URL hasn't been changed.

What you probably want is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and the details, your suggestion was right. It helped me to fix this issue. Sorry but I cannot vote up for you as I am new here :(

Comment: Don't worry about upvotes, accepting the answer is enough and will also give you a rep boost.